# Are software comparisons allowed and if so how broad are you allowed to be?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, asking-questions

Are software comparisons considered on-topic here? I mean Ubuntu software of course, and probably software which is specific to it or at least Linux but runs on Ubuntu. And how broad is considered 'too broad' in this case? I mean, can you just ask what is the difference and why you would use one over the other? Or do you have to be more specific than that?

Comment: I'd say we shouldn't. Impossible to make it without mixing in opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "too broad" close reason is reserved for open-ended questions that require a book to be written to answer them.

You're asking us to say whether a hypothetical class of question is off-topic without an example. It's *entirely* possible that you can have a great question that is in the form of a "software comparison", just as it's possible there can be real steamers.

I have no interest in banning software comparisons. Just look at them on a case-by case basis. If questions...

- ... can be answered
- ... can be answered without writing a book
- ... can be answered objectively (or at least with objective rationale)
- ... is about Ubuntu

It's *probably* okay. Or duplicate. Or something else. Honestly, who knows until we're looking at it.

Comment: **:D** +1 for *"until we're looking at it."*

Comment: So if there are two very similar packages, can one ask what the difference is between them? Such as one package that claims to have Unity integration or something, and the other doesn't but you can't tell what the actual difference between them is.